# React: setState can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I need a setState inside a timeout in my component, so I've done this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timeouts.push(setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ text: 2 });
  }, 4000));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.timeouts = [];
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.
This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before you call setState your component will be mounted but your component is not mounted

Comment: @IhorSkliar componentDidMount is being called after the component has mounted, so setting state in the componentDidMount function wont be a problem

Comment: @IhorSkliar I'm using inside componentDidMount, so it's mounted.

Comment: Is it anywhere else that you are using setState

Comment: @MatheusLima when your setState was called, your component is unmounted, don't forget you are using timeout!

Comment: No, that's the only one @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: @IhorSkliar If I'm calling it inside the componentDidMount function, why the timeout thing matters?

Comment: @MatheusLima your timeout can executing in any component lifecycle period

Comment: Does your component unmount within that 4 second frame?

Comment: I think that more code of the component could help. What are you using `this.timeouts` for? When is that timeout fired? Storing something directly as an attribute of `this` is usually very problematic in React.

Comment: @MatheusLima you don't call it in componentDidMount, you just set the timeout! setState will be called when is timeout will be triggered and in this time your component may be unmounted or remounted! Be careful with timeouts!

Comment: @NickZuber I think that this is it! I'm probably not unmounting it properly. I'll update the question.

Comment: You should be clearing the timeouts when you unmount the component, and I think @IhorSkliar is right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `componentWillUnmount` to clear the timeouts properly. You need to make use of `clearTimeout` to clear the timeout instead of emptying the array.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timeouts.push(setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ text: 2 });
  }, 4000));
}

clearTimeouts: function() {
  this.timeouts.forEach(clearTimeout);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.clearTimeouts();
}
```